# Check if a value exists in an object array without for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
"Roles":
{ 
    "0_A":["Developer"],
    "0_B":["Developer"],
    "0_C":["Developer","Tester","Player"],
    "0_D":["Tester"]
}
```

Is there a way to check if the value 'Player'/'Tester'/'Developer' exists anywhere in 'Roles' object? This is what I tried:

```
let isPlayer= false;
if (response) {
  const k = Object.keys(response["Roles"]);
  for (let index = 0; index < k.length; index++) {
    if (response["Roles"][k[index]].indexOf("Player") > -1) {
      isPlayer= true;
      break;
    }
  }    
}
```

Is there a way to do this without for loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in conjunction with [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) over the [Object.Values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the input object. An example fo how to do this is shown on the below snippet:

```js
const response = {};
response["Roles"] = {
  "0_A":["Developer"],
  "0_B":["Developer"],
  "0_C":["Developer","Tester","Player"],
  "0_D":["Tester"]
};

const checkForType = (resp, type) =>
{
    let typeExists = false;

    if (resp)
    {
        let roles = resp["Roles"] || {};
        typeExists = Object.values(roles).some(arr => arr.includes(type));
    }

    return typeExists;
}

console.log(checkForType(response, "Player"));
console.log(checkForType(response, "Developer"));
console.log(checkForType(response, "Team Leader"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as below:

```
let isPlayer = false;
if (response) {
  const roleNames = Object.values(response["Roles"]);
  const playerFound = roleNames.find(names => names.includes('Player'))
  isPlayer = !!playerFound;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [*flatten*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the 2D array returned by [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the array contains the role name:

```js
const response = {
  "Roles": {
    "0_A": ["Developer"],
    "0_B": ["Developer"],
    "0_C": ["Developer", "Tester", "Player"],
    "0_D": ["Tester"]
  }
}

let isPlayer = Object.values(response.Roles)
                      .flat()
                      .includes("Player")
                      
console.log(isPlayer)
```